# Blob connector in logic app in global cloud unable to access blob in china cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-logic-apps

I have scenario where  my logic app in global cloud has to connect blob in "azure china" . I am getting the below error. I have to connect to "core.chinacloudapi.cn" while adding connection string. How do i achieve it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few limitations for azure from China server side .You can read more about it [here](https://www.azure.cn/en-us/home/features/products-by-region)